# Fatal error...Please help me

Tags: fatal-error

I am New to wordpress After installing and activating a plugin I got the following error

( ! ) Fatal error: Cannot declare class WP_Importer, because the name is already in use in C:\wamp2\www\wordpress\wp-admin\includes\class-wp-importer.php on line 5

Please help me, how to fix this error...

Comment: You have another plugin/theme adding the `WP_Importer` class. Did you install any recent plugin/theme that broke the website?

Comment: or are you trying to include the class file anywhere without using `require_once` or `include_once` ?

Comment: Yes I installed a plugin and after activating it that what happened

Comment: go in the `wp-content/plugins` folder and change/delete the folder of the plugin you installed. It will work again after that. You should also open a ticket with the plugin developer and describe the problem.

Comment: Many thanks to you sir... It worked ... thank you soooooo much

Comment: Glad I could help. I added an answer with the solution. Thank you for marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have another plugin/theme adding the `WP_Importer` class. Did you install any recent plugin/theme that broke the website?

If you did install a plugin that broke the website go in the `wp-content/plugins` folder and change/delete the folder of the plugin you installed. It will work again after that.

You should also open a ticket with the plugin developer and describe the problem.